# rosmake markers rviz

Tags: rviz, rosmake, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to visualize an object that is based on points_and_lines.cpp in the rviz points and lines tutorials. However, when I change something to the cpp source and subsequently rosmake and rosrun the code, the old object keeps displayed. I have the feeling that rosrun runs an old executable or that rosmake does not properly renews the executable.

Do you have any idea how I can remove the 'old' executable that rosrun calls such that I am sure rosmake creates a new executable.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10705/rosmake-markers-rviz/) by [Wouter](https://answers.ros.org/users/879/wouter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2011-07-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wouter](https://answers.ros.org/users/879/wouter/) on 2011-07-24**:
I have tried to do that but something seems to be wrong with 'rosmake'. It doesn't compile, it hangs and only gives this output: wouter@localhost:~/using_markers$ rosmake --pre-clean using_markers stem
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['using_markers', 'stem']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/wouter/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110725-133557

**Comment by [Bram van de Klundert](https://answers.ros.org/users/392/bram-van-de-klundert/) on 2011-07-24**:
have you tried calling "rosmake --pre-clean" (cleaning the executable before the build)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently there was something wrong with my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. the exported directory was my home/wouter/ directory and causes ros to search infinitely long for the package. Once changed to home/wouter/ros the issue was resolved.

Thanks Lorenz Mosenlechner

---

Originally posted by [Wouter](https://answers.ros.org/users/879/wouter/) with karma: 130 on 2011-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0